# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'applogger'@'10.26.72.109' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect my mysql server from remote host (IP: **10.26.72.109**) with username '**applogger**' and having above mentioned error.

when I checked mysql user table, I think it's having enough privileges.

```
mysql> select host,user from mysql.user where user='applogger'  order by host desc, user desc;;
+---------------+-----------+
| host          | user      |
+---------------+-----------+
| ms.portal-01  | applogger |
| localhost     | applogger |
| 10.26.72.70   | applogger |
| 10.26.72.109  | applogger |
| %             | applogger |
+---------------+-----------+
```

Here **ms.portal-01** and **10.26.72.70** are same hosts and I can successfully make mysql connection from that servers.

According to the [Mysql refernace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html), Mysql server will load user privileges based on host and user most specific values.

How can I make the mysql connection from **10.26.72.109** successfully?

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw) helps

Comment: Thanks @kellymandem. It's working now

Comment: you are welcome. I recommend that you post an answer on how you solved it so it helps others who will experience a similar problem in future